# How to insert dynamic fields into text stored as string in another table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have one table that stores a text string with different paragraphs (dbo.Documents). The user needs to edit the text in dbo.Documents.DocText whenever he or she needs to. And there is another table, dbo.Clients, that stores the client info (brand, name, address, etc...)

I need to find a way that the client's data gets printed in different areas of the text stored in dbo.Documents.DocText.

For example, the text is for a contract, so in some lines of that contract we need to print the client's name, VAT number, address, etc...

"This an example text where ClientsName will get a contract from ProvidersName, and they will do business".

That text must be editable and ClientsName and ProvidersName will come from another table, according to the client that logged into de application.

So far I haven't been able to find something usefull on this matter, I've tryed the Conact function, but it's not working, also a JOIN, but I don't now how to fix the field.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide some details if you want any help here. Let's start with the table definition and an explanation of what you want to do. As posted this just doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: A JOIN is the correct solution.   Please post your attempt to solve this with a JOIN so that we can debug it.

Comment: Is there any way to join documents table ? If no , then use cross join with clients table and use replace function to change text based on client.